# Adjusting brightness and contrast levels on streaming media

Tags: video, video-streaming

I wonder if it is possible to adjust brightness and contrast levels within a streaming video on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu is an OS not a program. What program is being used to view the video?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Look into Firefox configuration options.